# How avoid error - function-name(...) is not a function in quiz?

Tags: javascript, function

I want pass quiz from codewars - https://www.codewars.com/kata/53cf7e37e9876c35a60002c9/train/javascript, but I can not avoid an error to pass :"TypeError: add(...) is not a function"

```js
function curryPartial(){
  let args= [...arguments]
  let fn = args[0]
  console.log(fn.length)
  function cur(){
    let argsCur= [...arguments]
    return curryPartial(...args,...argsCur)
  }
  cur.valueOf = ()=>{
    //return args.reduce((a,b)=>a+b)
    // console.log(...args)
    // const res = +fn(...args.slice(1))
    // return res
  }
  return cur

}
function add(a, b, c) {
  return a + b + c;
}
console.log(+curryPartial(add(1,2)(3)))
```

How I can avoid this error to pass the quiz ?

Comment: What you are trying to do in `add(1,2)(3)`? as it's written now, the parser expect from the `add(1, 2)` to return a function, so you can call it with argument `3`. but it's return a number. Since the `add` function expect 3 arguments, I assume you want the `3` to be the third argument of the `add` function. if so, you have to write it as `add(1, 2, 3)`

Comment: ```All these examples should produce the same result:

curryPartial(add)(1)(2)(3); //6
curryPartial(add, 1)(2)(3); //6
curryPartial(add, 1)(2, 3); //6
```

Comment: The `curryPartial()` itself return a function, so you can call the return value. but the `add` function return just a number. how you expect to call it as a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### That's about the `add(1,2)(3)`

Of cause you get errors, the `add` function returns a value, by doing `add(1,2)(3)` you are executing the return value of `add(1,2)` with passing a `3`, which is not a function, so the error has been raised.

the execute statement should be

```js
console.log(+curryPartial(add)(1,2)(3))
// not
console.log(+curryPartial(add(1,2)(3)))
```

pay attention to the parentheses pair